# Datatables get values from display table (not initial table set by data option)

Tags: javascript, datatables-1.10

I am bit confused about handling the datatables. I created a simplified example with an array of object (each row containing a single timestamp) as datasource and create a 4 column datatable out of it:

```
$('#myTable').DataTable({
        "columns": [{
          "title": "Date",
          "data": "createTime",
          "orderData": 1,
          "render": function(data,type,row,meta){return moment.unix(data).format(moment.localeData().longDateFormat('LL'));}
      },
      {
          "title": "0_hidden_createTime",
          "data": "createTime",
          "visible": false,
          "searchable": false
      },
      {
          "title": "Button Column",
          "className": "dt-right",
          "render": function(data,type,row,meta){return '<button onclick="doIt($(this).closest(\'tr\'));return false;">Press Me</button>';}
      },
      {
        "title": "hidden_id",
        "visible": false,
        "render": function(data,type,row,meta){return new Date().getTime();}
      }],
      data: [
        {
          "createTime": 1570032790
        },
        {
            "createTime": 1572711189
        },
        {
            "createTime": 1575303183
        },
        {
            "createTime": 1577981593
        },
        {
            "createTime": 1580660000
        },
        {
            "createTime": 1583165589
        },
        {
            "createTime": 1585843981
        }
      ]
    });
```

The logic behind the 4 columns:

- Date: A date formatted date from the datasource timestamp, ordered by hidden column
- 0_hidden_createTime: orderby column for the "Date" column
- Button Column: Button to do an action on a each row
- hidden_id: a column which contains a unique id (here simplified by timestamp) which I would use later

Now after I click on a button I would like to get those hidden values to do something with it. But it seems to be very difficult to get those values. I already saw that it maybe is inside the "context" object of:

```
function doIt(row){
  $('#myTable').DataTable().rows(row).data().context[0]
}
```

But I can't find any useful docs on how to retrieve hidden values. Can you please open this blackbox for me? I would expect a simple call like `.rows().data()` for all values actually are in the visible table (like getting the above 4 rows and values)

Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

So then, after there isn't an answer so far, I created a hack to get all the values I need. For sure there is a much better way but till then, here it is a working solution. This function collects the value visible on the screen from within the datatable. It also will collect values from hidden columns set by either defaultContent or render fn.

Be advised, this works in our specific case (ie. we use input data like an array of objects and so on), in case you do it another way the function maybe breaks.

```
/**
   * Function returns the value for a specific row and specific column. Unless specified by @forceVisibleValue, the 
   * function will return the column from input data if existing.
   *
   * @el:                   HMTLElement: from within the table, typically a clicked button
   * @column:               String: The target column name, can be from both sources - initial data or visible table
   * @forceVisibleValue:    Boolean: Force the method to return the visible column if exists (just incase your input data and output data has the same column name.
   */
  getDataFromColumn: function(el,column,forceVisibleValue){

    var row = $(el).closest('tr'),
        tableId = $(el).closest('table').attr('id'),
        table = $('#'+tableId).DataTable(),
        row = table.rows(row),
        value = row.data()[0][column];

    if(!forceVisibleValue && value)
      return value;

    if(!value || forceVisibleValue){
      //maybe one of the hidden columns
      var aoCols = row.context[0].aoColumns;
      for(var colIdx in aoCols){
        if(aoCols[colIdx]['title'] == column){
          if(aoCols[colIdx]['sDefaultContent'])
            return aoCols[colIdx]['sDefaultContent'];
          else if(aoCols[colIdx]['render']){
            var data = aoCols[colIdx]['data'] ? row.data()[0][aoCols[colIdx]['data']] : null,
                rowIdx = row[0][0],
                colIdx = table.context[0].oInit.columns.findIndex(function(obj){return obj.title == column;});
            return aoCols[colIdx]['render'].call(this,data,aoCols[colIdx]['sType'],row.data()[0],{settings: row.context[0], row: rowIdx, col: colIdx});
          } else
            return null;
        }
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
```